# Pip unable to find deepspeech / deepspeech-gpu from versions on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, conda, speech-to-text, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm trying to install deepspeech from Pypi on windows, I keep running into the issue of "Could not find required package from versions", my pip is up-to-date though ( 19.0.1).

I already tried some solutions given here: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/pip-install-deepspeech-doesnt-find-a-valid-deepspeech-when-mac-osx-10-11-is-used-and-not-mac-osx-10-12/22788

and here: https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/1519

but none of these solutions are neither concrete or specific to windows OS.

a "pip install --verbose deepspeech-gpu" gives me the following output

```
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7mrrmziw
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-cu5x3to6
Created requirements tracker 'C:\\Users\\amith\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-cu5x3to6'
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4yft_h15
Collecting deepspeech-gpu
  1 location(s) to search for versions of deepspeech-gpu:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
  https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/deepspeech-gpu/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/9c/fa724b84dcfc339becdabdb75e6cca285549fac43c6f884d5904ca89b545/deepspeech_gpu-0.0.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=6dbaf5785f044cb535f2a9175cc8be1d86ace498a6a1e29d93bf5c6e4d253f9d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/a1/1f6ab6392f27cc1111a03f13b5e6a01999b1791a32c9a94add64caf9ef66/deepspeech_gpu-0.0.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=f5a814545898dbe7dc7810e879829fb847f0abe9fcec2d42f073b8b1a43bebd6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/7c/f7ad794d502cb9379f868cfa38dea6acf23600521af5f1cfcafe6fea3a1f/deepspeech_gpu-0.0.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=855350c36b2fc24bd4a3fb4f87e002fc27a45dd8df2e89fe5229d413f6419ef0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/d5/6353e181b9c0238e135f3aea86d07052c269c60a9bb5845816fea0d6bf39/deepspeech_gpu-0.0.3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=5f85ed962e7fedf3a5933f5ffdc0392c9cb78d3790eb2e4ee0ba569c1b76f497 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/c5/812c887dede79c1317c981c05d39e7d0fa01037a17ad6d5a3f1659209408/deepspeech_gpu-0.0.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=2a6d0063f442569735feceeb5a21431faae1e5de151948b94cd6e2a3f5a39fa0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/ee/08d840f14fd6807451eb0e653dc8ad9b7ec7e999282cc380a858c5fe0546/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=b14ddbe9037bd75df146b763e1c2261e9ee686a1e0291646afdbc961b9c64a0a (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/6f/14948a974a9c870da7dcf62bd1d19229a242adab2bdd832ded87ade798d2/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.0-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=81c60ef00a293e21ecf1fb305d54c783a0a86124b8bf1cdb49b54a56b183cc7f (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/6b/17ccbdf995caebbd2ab49b7b9c5e4b8fea7cf1898e82814d2b0e9619c93e/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=f2e669650c169e1e5ba2dd85326beda2549d40ba1ff91c8c6fcd769bce628b11 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/0a/8592152688e8e65712097062e9473fe6db93b36ca50c859c8ca078c38b30/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=c96e53091bb3a6b735109de2f331eaa4dae3744040519a74dd7c94cef417d5d4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/8d/d58a81cfe1684a3e48b6babd133e859b49a3ba1db2c7b6b6bcbaab7a47b1/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=c39ae34d33294cfdee37c1d51e891537d71d5f53bb0249f079891d117111149e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/34/fa99d98fad31de222d9690388aa9ea240e90f8ff3f31524acfab4d6bc43d/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=d6f0fa10d82a8d954696d761fa9f966911126ec2911e6b28a67973f4ba2ee58a (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/86/2ab8d516bcf2fe9b2e48bbe82ccb7c75a0ef72db211b6d076e60f2c6e81b/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=3d4d99a4714975564397e7150dbb5b09ba814ac571d67bc5b95351153f10fed4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/51/7b3b25a3f43b964a9625c17d38a5c40c2d45c28dc4d342788dc3dfef6cb9/deepspeech_gpu-0.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=5bd86718e5f58286fc82e2c0e4a42e9d725e1bf284e82895426236c3dd18a01c (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/63/2d8c370b28610511d88d1812dbc14c4cea13cdab24c6aad460f309f476d1/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e6b70f7a1c0bcf938379c471ddb4813b9d8fa8816a8fc67db840d31867292b13 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/5a/72a90d566942705859ee6f04f4939382d1d060ca62104f14caadf085ca54/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=7ec0af8ff749ee2392ec72dbdebee66a12c367e593ea00efc4b58c661ba26556 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/fd/6a78ec4c5c32fb7bf596dbb511fa4a316ab8fb0347cf5f8cb2cfbe01c45d/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a0-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=74a3efe5274b7a601f3af607f2106323e2297433a25d83da3fef1024dd60d2db (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/14/53bfafde17adb5235d74c9beb0262f2bdd5120d2fcef3504eb98bddf10e5/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=3d96aec0c895c601f03a8ed265b4545ec6ae9164432546c002ac17f1f03f863a (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/3e/35a3af055589dbea50a547c9cc4b84ae6d84d253ade9e925ac23d9d1180b/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=9727bb19a07f1d1777365f2809886ae05228f7e1e59c1bebbc2a847181a322f9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/5d/7e71a446466a5cb6fecff0c0bd9a0812dc24f313ec2745a462cf78968e34/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a1-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=53b0fbefc817c84660fac935e82c9c867604c7d183097ec7e7806dad85308de3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/97/8a86376563c682af94d0c40a969c7e99ac117f0fad203aa95c2e9202587f/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=149ac68095ebc6aa834d2131722db85f3ca2b8af3f9eee52d539602f7b0765a8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/6d/789938137131fb1e37a3625d423787cd8c8a2e26eba478f97385eb4e16fa/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=553b328c8d8bdae6887df52ea6ff44ed0c1ae6d768951a3afcad41d944362a1d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/d1/cafe28b86a2665e6c31c896efeae73f0d7d52a2325c975bd08383dbe12ac/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=52344fcd23a40e1564965fdb906938e5afe3f3b8bdb0b3ec2d32bee049492e12 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/c2/d2c58592d92d3beb827902a58b03eaf3e3c6ac794c2a62ca4741bc9b30d4/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=d12b563affde620dbc5fe2ba63febea1a36326e84cf0f4b009800a63117da424 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/b3/24b45f05be4593feb5487cf0ccf866baff43cd035d42d3808d05a7a5f1d0/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a2-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=2ad18cccd377c3b183ffea4ae5d72ea8beea4d6dd0d979b811b1f333f19a950b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/bc/3180f2e78b2eaadaba4b10ecbff9162be3f040c9fbfe50ed4828c25cf67f/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e343a1adaa656a824865df6e2490192ac2ca95a8bacc598aa1abc2974240f2ef (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/f4/d066db76439c0f43759c98c7a20a3c2c51f005e146d2005a229d1a430bc8/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a2-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=415a21264dc44b0ea642c02a24acf08f48d56e8d6080849850292ef3334318be (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/f7/b5a23a8905604c3f6931c3da05df37ab9773f3efa2f19bfbfed0dbfc1ac3/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=6466e8f5b129c9783e1048c2d4d484d2268385a99ab4db4df0f2155bc6b1d0ea (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/d1/6b288dac2fafb7b5b7a220ee0b87e49bcca3f56baef3e2a67f6d5c6b5e89/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=646455e14765f7e1ba095186daa60138dc3e397bcfb5de83cb814979704b1357 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/41/7bce2c3a0b15af929697e753c4d29cffe396fd4e9a5bc37c6c518d814c58/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a3-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=ca6711673dd14f69b45d7d6ddfc089ba9ada5b8ede2c30511d8d7db1ae221d48 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/0d/74a17b044b91f9476a8196a19ae4e25bf839c4a64791a080c5781f41b44b/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=00eeed1af81e704752a07c3c1478a356ed5a52287bd61c42860a02d053a211b0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/79/3a360e37607178215205c09619c19e75dc77a2237086f953801070235770/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=2f660024e49f6e77e9f9e782725891361b79f8f15d7660839840ab5793354e6d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/09/9d08bf8100771d9693f2d53410147fd44ab3c6aaccbbef769111aabb2b7b/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e5b58bb1345e82bc3605b4c655738b2d3ebb546d6c5d0b261ee596b433feb604 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/d1/1706e4b4b623f9c448198251ce65a194c1d27da7a11049f3c3ea86fa0dc0/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=4b3cfb1fb86dc627df287ac5888387438f13cc17dc0947bf889626d914f165b6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/63/2f977d340e041e0671853176c67742a800f8645053d43afcfc699b5f0746/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a4-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e3f4fd27d35c04e20b6c65b60d45ded70f5d838be7914f10c91fe4f7690ac666 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/47/c478a9eccb502a9fab9dbaec7ec1c98cc42623ddd737d8b159870e00b272/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=42df25d3c0d8687da457fb894e83202256fdc2984168bb25845d81ede23a4376 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/7d/7c3757e78413a2a459f329d2871ddf3c6efa5fd8114dc97359375274c1dd/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a4-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=69f6e4f91328496b0d4a6369bf17af7899a3d05f9b25a20dd35b0e7999b6aaf3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/18/5cdb83587124d776f804eda3845c456803741f7de180b19e1957e49f84bd/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=27a4cbda194e783ceae4c782d97fe6183f75f7b2bb2fa336b678617e3ace1bba (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/e9/dae7d306eeccf4561f8dd34adccec8a55e50a970146696ea692fb587fdc3/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=2e05745159088d79d651962cb78fa484b98c0b5fc7d3c2cd3bc97d0096d8c411 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/6a/48812f2d333b1aec258cf8c4e53ecf360536d4edf0e0c591639e28e7cf89/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a5-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=3ab65455ef646f4b4b96cdc7b3de6020584f6cac97040f873b940af5c620996b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/37/e7ea484b1e42bf87648b2de4345cba5ca36ecc5ece1984b90550f70ec98a/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=8a941750236e6994c1aa486912dd0810e40748fe0b1d24893c24595969835dd9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/39/ea9847ffe7b395ef114a7f07097a21c7166596b57e17d8c5780dd0c2636f/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a5-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e15a513e170f6a8903acfd1fd64ed2495a7e475fe64baeadbe5c03f71bda8a22 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/70/523a472dc93a67fc67626f2c8079326f4622223d0ed63304a5541f82e613/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a5-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=53cc640d1c469620ce2605f16a7181c7c03f34eadf725afa809672a24dc7a9c7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/da/c628061faafa88b70dfc8642d1098855ae937825622511eea45e30505197/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=a9f81d11fb59b08028b431b292cbf0d752bbbd770f7f6b58febaa27df9caed44 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/8c/c915e970b28298826e7dc72aa76c64eed7e5d3b6d798f2ce2c8d9588b07f/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a6-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=90bf05c99af766399a78731299190af53751d7bb5cb14a70f7b867eb3c5fbe02 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/bb/66f34a9618249a375a2b5652c52ffe4dd2f2acce14589fd35a81c0dd8408/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a6-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=d51b8d5085a84e493cd4e70cf0b99f71348c2d11f753960537ec1f4d5648a6d6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/83/ed3137a1dec3bb6aa94b22154291e1054b2720f6f6e39eabbbfac9ab6431/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a6-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=4c27cabbed1674f2f76379b0ab703c01aa4697f3c170393ad4c1e40ed4d8310f (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/71/cf285a62d04d0a481e47a92fea7f1f770a4a29002f671a8adac0f7a954ac/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a6-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=1842691807746752b9a7aca70d929c99abbf1ab006139138058130f2e9aaab07 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/63/6cd32c74430df6b9bb340d52dd8fddbfc696493ac8c43291e04854690dc0/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a6-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=49a20ecb1e323b4d2758a2898d7835d83f80f9d745f8b90c87ed9a287b1ede0f (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/c0/912930cd93b188bb4289992a5d52f6e2cb36ea1c1d5a1c36004daea892bd/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a6-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e7aea8825842bd73e461d2842e2e5439cb0cdb2158af54c61f0df205b274a7d6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/51/a1fcdf0de6c1c7c6f9e0af18307fc22323db06f5c73dbed306b2e618be49/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a7-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=f4b01a336a2c820b83aea29b16c7ee1d999edaeb2a49b60a7ae4b937e9551bbc (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/da/48e4dbf82142c56966f5d228e99e766733663f520cac5b67236cfcfc4e92/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a7-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=6c819f84c692b6206b57cb2cd50a89a561d12d58cb69fb13d30c7e0c6ecc5e74 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/12/8eb46e6ec9f27f1690fdc3c8d0fb9ee6ff50ed42da22abd682408bbc03c3/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a7-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=58f64614433ecb0e0b5ef648bdfe34820fe9ac27334ea84ea782b78f8a33b9ea (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/cc/5a22979d5a454ce1260320ecfd26bb64056a435180c1bece244af0487acf/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a7-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=20473eaaac1b0d51e3a74ca31344f7f3cc3f1b20ce3e5dd9908af23adf33c3f2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/73/5fc90ead16e4139881008ffdf6a8a6be7d938705ab4b61ab48fdc9aacafe/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a7-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=144ef00f4d986cec322f63311759993e3e9417c61cff842f539576729f82718e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/72/c303a935d56fb048c37de0787561385f9ed8d7fa60addfb9a089c0acee1b/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a7-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=8a5c21976ae08d41deaad33008b8d54ee7ebf89ab10b7dd9bedda816d5158fd9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/b0/1200cf949cb22ab3579fb1dc29471e491e7148b8a5fb8a85f82c322e2c0f/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a8-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=f5d0e16a93830e42205c568e75c6a068e4805787d4cf2801ff36c8c44d03b4f0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/60/e4fdf4bfc40d1807e73e5d26992751e792cc980d10d1af0b69c5f65f4f3e/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a9-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=63c651de353c9210682cbd9b2c44fb90d2d507102de93ddbf13273cd881c4946 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/05/11a61dda3c1ea79406c4d2fed2190627b058a85701eb9a3dcba77f4e84ed/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a9-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=2f082b74bdf62cfd92a39c7b19afd3abedc53535793aa8542f386f4b44011f8c (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/5c/03c1e45343eb16b8eb44c407a7ba8e55972fdda23fcbd3fc020ca48fd0a1/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a9-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=8388533cbebd98a3e2bee9cb13cfde451f0471d51993cb4e6fda2371cdf85ce2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/3f/6b451fac0f07ef2bbaed2e1a85a74fd21427f3593855da33c2b68c413a26/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a9-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=d72b04b13f46b88fb418ccd55df0792b4ea07d03c755331061213e5eab0cd2d9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/b2/9cef3a6d3c76320d3517d1ee2a9f8df861868df13a5632aa971052bfdcb0/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a9-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=040f9d478243e9d07477faa73903c2d91cc9e9050286a381af504b2d5b57ded3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/d9/a300fe27264a98eaabffd8ad0070531fce14e9426ce9426a406240b2fa6a/deepspeech_gpu-0.2.0a9-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=dedfe5668d42007c3196f6cc087ef120283549ea610b0693975028b4cd84b01d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/52/10f9319a58c42678439f49a5d6fc02a0f3d51376efaa92387a0ee19f6955/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=2843b8899e423f6631496b191d3a5359a88d507b64bbe5db0e5f60fd23dd8f43 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/b6/7c5c84a46444d0077c50418bb4e724df3a146d5449729cf33f8271de9f0e/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=8a6d2b82e47dbc3c2316b20c98a97355feb9c5918460b6fd3c259b4d496395fe (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/e6/8867b98b43894152b4e70b1e3a4fd3eb0cf08e1d82a67595d3fc2e07f4dd/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=d862833c40fd7ea6fe29f7a2fc5b0ec0355e26ce1814e6ad072403260abdff01 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/08/470f5e49d178403d2bb6b22a0856f566b6eb4beb07101b29250c6c90bd88/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a3-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=bf5b745ab915850f007a0617a911cfe9913d4602b3c9f0f7862651cac45de5df (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/f1/f05c794256d2073213a9637d4c2439cc86cb3b512ff438cd94187979f01c/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=fdca4f40aceee0fe708e0f511811c8a6990d8cf7f1492a9181f16b30b05c4bf2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/5a/a818740dd81dbc36ccde180c8899187a9aab71709aeb4caf96936c8754ec/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=0ae5bea1b4b678a5912fe46c465b8aa7bd5bf19ced04d58adc764f3b280fa158 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/cb/511efcdd4d4189d8b9b784a89dc98a5796166bc85893b1a19d54152c670f/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=295fa50dc464a1138acbc948ff9afb7d9086edc42bdce81fec85c7c3f8b193e2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/ac/81edc19378e43775d20389ea567c5dbb47b5459c0902dda68ed87f13bdd1/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=816e65826fe163d45d235069ef20f1f465bed57ea6b28a44910762a2e1c84a38 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/db/69f93ba59ecb31acff2cb4d02972a5aaa50f4a1c73acd3be00ad5db367d6/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=b05a8e83c79c1fa32067d0aa8152cc969f8a2120624964d461c1803aec078bac (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/05/0b0fd97c42242b9e1c1da8a65aa085ad1aa4a478268c7f2605bd9ff037b8/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a4-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=33862051b0ac960cc1d494c168c82d3aeb88002183cb453ab8c88f64a42c253e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/63/3d0342a9fbbf7b214c57fbe144c5a83835ba090031af23fd92424c3f90ce/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=40405c6942b99fb9b2a26fe4a67339d510d899a44ed06e05f6462e0f8de225e5 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/60/822e16adefb72c7ca385bfb1e842852a6e5affc56bd553cbe376c4382073/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a4-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e040a41e8be34765307d677d6e286b68c170f3f27f36d009f9aa9bed313dd9c2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/3a/c08c46fb87dd7cf72b5072e337fea5e83e7df00e9c03eab8afa07614ac41/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=b8f10d6290b9f916a881d8e4e8f3b3a11cb13f57832c77285c4f9f2c7f602f73 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/74/ed42a2f24d61ae00207790ecdebfb4f16a9c2d39034928ed0b65c97c6f10/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=bb29cd3abac87461688b9557b64f88bb3d0f9819255f9692b3804b551a9a9f40 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/2a/1f03f42732a62954fc0bc1b2aa2a48b3807feabece288f65b0c559e91e98/deepspeech_gpu-0.5.0a4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=9c1cf2a9ff7f5bb46ade39f3997684bf00414fba9d20f4f2695a959da26c5b8e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deepspeech-gpu/); it is not compatible with this Python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech-gpu (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker 'C:\\Users\\amith\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-cu5x3to6'
No matching distribution found for deepspeech-gpu
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 269, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 196, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\DrivenBI\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 688, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for deepspeech-gpu
```

seems like some CONFIG variables are unset, but not entirely sure on how to rectify them. And the tutorials from Pypi:

https://pypi.org/project/deepspeech/#using-the-python-package

clearly shows they have this package in place.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: They do not support Windows, try something else

Answer (score 1):

DeepSpeech as of now do not support windows, not through pypi anyway.
if you headover to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/deepspeech/#files) you will not find any windows binding there.

If you still want to try deepspeech on windows there is this [guides](https://fotidim.com/deepspeech-on-windows-wsl-287cb27557d4) you can go through..

Comment: Does it supports  ubuntu??? Because I am also trying to install it but it gives the same error as : ```No matching distribution  found for deepespeech``` I am using ```pip install deepspeech```